# How to delete duplicates (not distinct)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select the airports from routes, the thing is that the airport pairs are shown 2 times:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1gVe.jpg)

I want to show only the half (for ex. only BZK DME and not BZK DME and DME BZK)

```
SELECT 
   departure_airport, 
   arrival_airport, 
   departure_city, 
   arrival_city, 
   count (departure_airport) as sum
FROM 
    routes
GROUP BY
    departure_airport, 
    arrival_airport, 
    departure_city, 
    arrival_city
HAVING  
    count (departure_airport) > 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<`:

```
select r.*
from routes r
where departure_airport > arrival_airport;
```

This assumes that all routes have exact pairs.  This is suggested by your question.

Comment: Question, what happen on tie ? like show-off flight that take off and land on the same airport ?

Comment: @blag . . . That seems unlikely in a system of airline routes.  I do know that the Naples subquery has two stations with essentially the same latitude and longitude, but they have very different altitudes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That’s not an SQL specific reply, but I like the fact that you look at this specific case, which is why your reply is great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number() for Selecting particular Combinations of arrival airport and departure airport

```
(select departure_airport, arrival_airport, departure_city, arrival_city, 
count (departure_airport) as sum,row_number()(order by departure_airport,arrival_airport) as row
from routes
group by departure_airport, arrival_airport, departure_city, arrival_city
having count (departure_airport) > 2
 )where row=1
```